# Determining the type of an object in java

Tags: java, types

Say I have the following java code:

```
Object myObj = new ArrayList();
List myList = new ArrayList();
```

I would like to know how to determine which class or interface a given object is typed with.

Note that I am not talking of the type the object was instanciated from (here ArrayList) but rather the type on the left-hand side of the expression so that would be in the example above **Object** for myObj and **List** for myList.

How do I call this "left-hand side" type in proper parlance?

Also, how do I call the "right-hand side" type?

How do I determine programmatically what is this "left-hand side" type?

Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type used on the left-hand side is not the type of an *object*. It's the type of a *variable*. (The static or compile-time type.)

It's worth differentiating between a variable and an object - a variable has a name, a type and a storage location. The storage location contains value compatible with the type of the variable.

Now to find the type of a *variable* at execution time, you'd need some sort of reference to the variable itself *as* a variable. For example, if it's a field (static or instance) you can fetch the appropriate [`Field`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html) reference, you can ask for the type using [`Field.getType()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getType%28%29).

If it's a *local variable* you'll find it a bit harder. If you can explain what you're trying to *achieve* (rather than the mechanism you think will help you achieve it) we may be able to help more.

Calling `myList.getClass()` or anything like that will *not* do what you want, because that will deal with the *value* of `myList`, not the variable itself.

Comment: thanks Jon. To sum up: in order to determine the dynamic type, I use getClass(). In order to determine the static type I have to resort to reflection and more specifically Field.getType(). Is this correct?

Comment: Never mind local variables. Instance variables will suffice. I was not trying to achieve anything particular. Just getting clear some concepts...

Answer (score 3):

The "left-hand side" type is called the *static type*.

The "right-hand side" type is called the *dynamic type*.

You can determine the dynamic type by calling `var.getClass()`.

One way to determine the static type is by using function overloads:

```
public static void f(Object var) { ... }
public static void f(List var) { ... }
```

When you call `f(var)`, the compiler will use the static type of `var` to call the correct function.

Comment: sure: myObj.appropriateMethod()==Object.class or myList.appropriateMethod()==List.class

Comment: getClass will help me with the dynamic type but not the static type won't it?

Comment: That's an interesting way of getting the static type without reflection! Thanks to you aix.